# How can I ignore emacs tempfiles in require_tree directives for snockets?

Tags: javascript, emacs, gruntjs, require

I am using snockets to construct my app.js like so:

```
//= require .bower_components/foo/foo.js
...

//= require_tree ./directives
//= require_tree ./services
...
```

I also use emacs, which means that when I use grunt to run this with:

```
snockets:
  'ui':
    minify: false
    src: 'app.js'
    dest: '_dist/app.js'
```

It errors out due to tempfiles:

`Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/apolishc/github/app/directives/.#foo.js'`

How can I pass snockets a list of patterns for files to ignore under require tree (tempfiles for emacs/vim/w/e)?